# How to center multiple columns relative to the whole table

Tags: css

Here's my goal:

[image]

In my effort of accomplishing it, I added a column left and right just to push content in the center, but the side-effect is that it squishes the text content too:

[image]

How do we make this happen but still give priority to the text content?

Here's my effort:
([Also in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tavufov/2/edit?html,output))

```html
  
  
  
  <style>
    
    table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%}
    tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:silver}
    td {padding: 1rem}
    
  </style>
  
  
  
  
  <table class="">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th style="width:50%"></th>
            <th class="">Position</th>
            <th class="">Description</th>
            <th style="width:50%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">1.</td>
            <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that `whitespace: nowrap` is not a solution as it may overflow text content out of the viewport. So we do need a wrap to happen, but only after there is no more horizontal space in the viewport:

[image]

Comment: Change your `<th style="width: 50%></th>` to Change your `<th style="width: 5%></th>`

Comment: @user2796515 the columns are not centered that way: http://jsbin.com/tavufov/1/edit?html,output

Comment: can you just remove the `text-align: right` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hgzu3cfk/ ?

Comment: @user2796515 that way the columns are centered relative to themselves. Not relative to the whole table.

Comment: sorry  I don't really get what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%}
        thead {width:100%;}
        tbody{width:100%;}
        tr{width:100%;}
        tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:silver}
        td,th {padding: 1rem 12.5%; text-align:center;width:50%;}
```

```html
<table class="">
        <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th class="">Position</th>
                <th class="">Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td class="">some content that shouldn't nextline</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: No. Try resizing your browser. You'll see multiple issues: When it's narrow the text wraps, altho there is a lot of room available; When it's wide, it's centered but the columns are not next to each other.